# Hashtable entries -> Combo box using a For Each loop vb.net

Tags: vb.net, foreach, hashtable

I've been given some code to work with that attempts to take values out of a hash-table and load them into a combo-box.

```
        Dim lstProductItems As List(Of Hashtable)

    ' Fill the product combobox with details from the product table.
    lstProductItems = oPurchaseOrderController.getAllProducts()
    For Each product In lstProductItems
        'cboItems.Items.Add(product("SKU") & " - " & product("ProductName"))
        cboItems.Items.Add(product("SKU") & " - " & product("ProductName"))
    Next
```

This is the code that was provided, it loads up a hashtable, then uses the for each loop to load them into a combo box items list.
It clearly doesn't work, as 'product' is a completely undeclared variable.

however, when i change 'product' to 'product as string' it throws me the error:
" Value of type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' cannot be converted to 'String'."

I have no idea how to alter this code to make it work, this faulty method of drawing from hashtables appears in many other areas in the code i was provided and apparently other people have gotten it to work.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Below is C# Code how to use Hashtable in for each loop.

```
    Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
    hashtable[1] = "One";
    hashtable[2] = "Two";
    hashtable[13] = "Thirteen";

    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
    }
```

Kindly go through http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashtable for details

Answer (score 0):

I wonder do you really need a List for your HashTable

```
Dim hashTable As New HashTable()
hashTable = oPurchaseOrderController.getAllProducts()
For Each item As DictionaryEntry In hashTable
    cboItems.Items.Add(item.Key + " - " + item.Value)
Next
```